# Is there any way to view the current queue size for a BGP neighbor in the Bird routing daemon?

Tags: routing, bgp

Using a Cisco or Juniper routers you can see the size of the output queue value by showing the bgp summary.  This information is also available when showing the detailed neighbor information.

e.g.

```
russell@juniper> show bgp summary
Peer                     AS      InPkt     OutPkt    OutQ   Flaps Last Up/Dwn State|#Active/Received/Accepted/Damped...
192.0.2.4             64496     112631     112606       0       1      5w1d9h Establ
```

or

```
cisco> show ip bgp nei 192.0.2.4
<snip>
Message statistics:
    InQ depth is 0
    OutQ depth is 0
```

This information can be extremely useful when tracking down convergence issues; however I cannot find any way to get at it using the bird routing daemon.

```
bird> show protocols all R64496x1
name     proto    table    state  since       info
R64496x1  BGP      T64496    up     Mar14       Established   
  Preference:     100
  Input filter:   ACCEPT
  Output filter:  ACCEPT
  Import limit:   15000
    Action:       restart
  Routes:         350 imported, 73881 exported, 133519 preferred
  Route change stats:     received   rejected   filtered    ignored   accepted
    Import updates:            375          0          0          0        375
    Import withdraws:           13          0        ---          0         13
    Export updates:        2627756        400          0        ---    2627356
    Export withdraws:      1640917        ---        ---        ---    1640945
  BGP state:          Established
    Neighbor address: 192.0.2.95
    Neighbor AS:      64496
    Neighbor ID:      192.0.2.95
    Neighbor caps:    refresh AS4
    Session:          external route-server AS4
    Source address:   192.0.2.254
    Route limit:      350/15000
    Hold timer:       82/90
    Keepalive timer:  16/30
```

Does anyone know how to get at this information when using bird?